# Angular 6 Create Json data using FormGroup or FormData?

Tags: angular, angular6

I need to create below JSON format using Angular 6 forms:

```
{
    "attribute":
    [
        {
            "name": "name", 
            "data": {"stringValue": "Tag 1"}
        }, 
        {
            "name": "tagname", 
            "data": {"stringValue": "Tag 1"}
        }, 
        {
            "name": "createdby", 
            "data": {"stringValue": "amit.vijay"}
        }
    ], 
    "name": "Tag 1", 
    "description": "",  
    publist: "ContentHub"
}
```

Can anyone help me to create this type of JSON using the FormGroup or FormData?

This JSON is posting on API server.

Anyone knows how OWCS Rest API works?

If you solve my problem that will be great help from your side.

Comment: what exactly want to create, FormGroup or FormData?

Comment: You're approaching the problem on the wrong foot. You have some information to gather, and to send to the server. The server expects this information in a given format. That doesn't mean that the form you use to gather the data must produce the data in that exact format. You're a programmer, so you can transform data in a given format to another format. So, design the best form you can, by reading the documentation, in order to gather the necessary data, then use your programmer skills to create the appropriate structure to send to the server.

Comment: And if you actually read the Angular documentation for forms, you'll realize that there is nothing named FormData here. So your question doesn't make much sense.

Comment: @JBNizet, I am creating this format using the string. But when i am using the file object then it is sending file object empty. So as per My  understanding we can send the file object using the FormData class.But when i am sending the data using the formData then it is sending me data in key:value pair not not in json obeject. My API server accept only json format in given above. So i need to convert form data in above given format. Hope it will clear more.

Comment: @JBNizet, In angular 6 we have a class const fd = new FormData(); to create a form data.  And we can append the field like this: fd.append('api_type','Login');